top forms sheaf and orientation sheaf
I'd like to know if the following is true:
Let $M$ be an $n$-dimensional smooth variety and define $o_M$ to be the orientation sheaf, that is the sheafification of the presheaf $U \mapsto H_n(M,M\smallsetminus U)$. Then $o_M \otimes C^{\infty}_M \cong \Omega^n_M$, the latter being the sheaf of top degree differential forms.
I feel this should be true, as the orientability condition can be expressed both in terms of the orientation sheaf and in terms of the existence of a volume form, so I guess what's missing to have an isomorphism between this two sheaves is the fact that $o_M$ is a sheaf of $\mathbb{Z}$-modules, while $\Omega^n_M$ is a sheaf of $C^{\infty}_M$-modules and to extend the ring over which a module is defined one usually tensorizes. In this case I guess we are tensorizing over $\mathbb{Z}$?
In case this were false, is there a similar relationship between the two sheaves?

In the case that $M$ is orientable, these two sheaves of $\mathcal{O}_X$-modules are isomorphic, because they are both free of rank $1$.
However, this isomorphism is not canonical, i.e. is not functorial in $M$. If it were, then the orientation bundle would have a canonical flat connection-- namely, the connection whose horizontal sections over $U$ are (the sheafification of) $H_n(M, M \setminus U, \mathbb{R})$. But this is not the case, since a diffeomorphism of $M$ can change the volume of a frame near $p$ and not near $q$.
